# How to make the export files (PPT or PDf) automatically uploaded to the website where the PowerBI report is embedded in?

Tags: powerbi

Currently the exported files (PPT or PDF) are automatically downloaded to the local PC.

Is there a way to make the exported files automatically uploaded to  the website where the PowerBI report is embedded in? The users would be able to download them if they like and they are granted the access. I have a security and confidential reason for this need, but cannot find a solution.

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: @K J, thank you for the comments. I was not accurate in the original expression of the question. What I really need is to have the exported files firstly uploaded to the website that the Power BI report is embedded in (and of course the users could download them to their local PC if they like), but not directly downloaded locally. I will do the modification.

Comment: @KJ , the clients I'm serving are my colleagues and the website is an internal one of the organization, it would be easier (and also safer) to share and work with the exported files if the files are by default stored on the website.